# String to Date parsing

Tags: c#, parsing, datatable

I am getting a string and i want to parse that string as date and want to store it in DataTable.

string can be in formats 
1- "2014/23/10"
2- "2014-23-10"

```
{
string st="2014/23/10";
string st="2014-23-10";
}
```

And attach time with it.

Any idea to make it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Since both are not *standart date and time format*, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` method like;

```
string st = "2014/23/10";
string st1 = "2014-23-10";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(st,
                   "yyyy/dd/MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(st1,
                   "yyyy-dd-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Output will be;

```
10/23/2014 12:00:00 AM
10/23/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/MogdD0)</kbd>.

Of course these outputs depends your current culture thread.

If you want to format your DateTime's as a string representation, you can use [`DateTime.ToString(string)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which accepts as a *string format*.

Since you have more than one format, you can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is takes your formats as a string array.

```
var formats = new []{"yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy/MM/dd"};
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(st, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
   //
}
else
{
  //
}
```

Comment: You've given two options, and which you use depends on the format of your input - I think the OP is looking for *one* option which will work with *both* formats. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes Jon, I was editing my answer the same time you write this comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) are appropriate here - both will accept multiple format strings, which is what you need in this case. Make sure you specify the invariant culture so that no culture-specific settings (such as the default calendar) affect the result:

```
string[] formats = { "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy/MM/dd" };
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, formats,
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // Add date to the DataTable
}
else
{
    // Handle parse failure. If this really shouldn't happen,
    // use DateTime.ParseExact instead
}
```

If the input is from a user (and is therefore "expected" to be potentially broken, without that indicating an error anywhere in the the system), you should use `TryParseExact`. If a failure to parse indicates a significant problem which should simply abort the current operation, use `ParseExact` instead (it throws an exception on failure).

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a `DateTime` with `DateTime.TryParseExact();` or even `DateTime.Parse` if you need to be flexible.  Then you can format it back out however you like!

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, use TryParseExact instead of parse

Comment: Try this:DateTime.Parse(st);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Parse(st);
```

If It the above line not works for you, then add cultrureInfo below:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(st,"yyyy/dd/MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get a `FormatException` saying that "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". This might be CultureInfo dependent, so even if it works on your machine, it may not on others depending on the the standard date formats for their culture.

Comment: It it's a cultrureInfo issue then you can try this: DateTime.ParseExact(st,"yyyy/dd/MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DateTime.Parse(st, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Set DateTimeStyles based on your requirement.